# Cuando la data cambia el Recyclerview se va al fondo [Android]

Tags: android, firebase, recyclerview

Actualmente tengo un chat donde envio y recibo mensajes, pero si hago scroll hacia arriba y recibo un mensaje automaticamente el recyclerview se mueve hasta el fondo, la idea es que cuando abra el chat el Recyclerview empiece en la parte inferior pero que cuando cambie la data (reciba un mensaje) no se mueva a la parte inferior.

```
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


   
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mMessageList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new MessageAdapter(this, mMessageList);



    
    mDatabaseRef.child("message").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            mMessageList.clear();

       

            // it iterates through all children of message
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                MessageModel upload = ds.getValue(MessageModel.class);


                mMessageList.add(upload);





            }


            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }



    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para alguien que le haya pasado lo mismo he encontrado la respuesta de una manera muy sencilla, resulta que el recyclerView esta seteando el adapdador cada vez que la data Cambia (se agrega un item) , la solucion es sacarlo del OnDataChange.

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);



recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
mMessageList = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new MessageAdapter(this, mMessageList);

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); //forma correcta 





mDatabaseRef.child("message").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        mMessageList.clear();

   

        // it iterates through all children of message
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            MessageModel upload = ds.getValue(MessageModel.class);


            mMessageList.add(upload);





        }





    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }



});
```